# Google place Не работает select

Tags: android, google-places-api

моя проблема состоит в следующем:
Я пишу приложение на android использую Google place API.

Все работает когда я пытаюсь выбрать ближайшее место, или ввести его в строке
Не работает когда я пытаюсь найти место по маячку на карте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ключ API проверял.Очень надеюсь на помощь т.к. долго уже не могу найти решение.

код вызова и результата:

```
 try {
                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(this);
                // Start the Intent by requesting a result, identified by a request code.
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);



                // Hide the pick option in the UI to prevent users from starting the picker
                // multiple times.


            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil
                        .getErrorDialog(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), this, 0);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services is not available.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1) {
        final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);

        Toast.makeText(this, place.getAddress(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();


        Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://unlimeted-house.firebaseio.com/users/" + userId);
        Map<String, Object> setLocation = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // setLocation.put("location", place.getAddress());
        double lati = place.getLatLng().latitude;
        double longi = place.getLatLng().longitude;
        //ref.child("locationlatitude").setValue(Double.toString(lati));
        //ref.child("locationlongitude").setValue(Double.toString(longi));

        newUser.put("locationlatitude", Double.toString(lati));
        newUser.put("locationlongitude", Double.toString(longi));

        ref.setValue(newUser);


        Location userLoc = new Location("asd");
        userLoc.setLatitude(place.getLatLng().latitude);
        userLoc.setLongitude(place.getLatLng().longitude);
        Hawk.put("userLoc", userLoc);
        plaseExists = true;


    }
}
```

Comment: ммм...что за ошибка то?) режим "Ванга" не всегда срабатывает)

Comment: Так проблема как раз в том что ошибки никакой нету. Я могу выбрать ближайшие места, но не могу выбрать место по маячку, не определяет абстрактное место. А в приложение примере все работает.